# SQL query with 6 checkboxes

Tags: c#, sql, database, checkbox, report

I have a report screen with 6 checkboxes that will tell which columns the report has to show. But when i check some checkboxes and click on the button nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LP12;Initial Catalog=SmmsData;Integrated Security=True");
connect.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = connect;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DrukSensor, FlowSensor, TempSensor, KwaliteitSensor, Toerental, OlieVerbruik"
+ " FROM SysteemSensorInfo"
+ " WHERE DrukSensor=@DrukSensor"
+ " AND FlowSensor=@FlowSensor"
+ " AND TempSensor=@TempSensor"
+ " AND KwaliteitSensor=@KwaliteitSensor"
+ " AND Toerental=@Toerental"
+ " AND Olieverbruik=@OlieVerbruik"
;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@DrukSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FlowSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TempSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@KwaliteitSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Toerental", SqlDbType.Bit);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OlieVerbruik", SqlDbType.Bit);

cmd.Parameters["@DrukSensor"].Value = CheckBoxDruk.Checked;
cmd.Parameters["@FlowSensor"].Value = CheckBoxFlow.Checked;
cmd.Parameters["@TempSensor"].Value = CheckBoxTemp.Checked;
cmd.Parameters["@KwaliteitSensor"].Value = CheckKwaliteit.Checked;
cmd.Parameters["@Toerental"].Value = CheckBoxToerenTal.Checked;
cmd.Parameters["@OlieVerbruik"].Value = CheckBoxOlieVerbruik.Checked;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

When I exclude this part of the code it works just fine but the checkboxes wont work.

```
+ " WHERE DrukSensor=@DrukSensor"
+ " AND FlowSensor=@FlowSensor"
+ " AND TempSensor=@TempSensor"
+ " AND KwaliteitSensor=@KwaliteitSensor"
+ " AND Toerental=@Toerental"
+ " AND Olieverbruik=@OlieVerbruik"
;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@DrukSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FlowSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TempSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@KwaliteitSensor", SqlDbType.Bit);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Toerental", SqlDbType.Bit);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OlieVerbruik", SqlDbType.Bit);

cmd.Parameters["@DrukSensor"].Value = CheckBoxDruk.Checked;
cmd.Parameters["@FlowSensor"].Value = CheckBoxFlow.Checked;
cmd.Parameters["@TempSensor"].Value = CheckBoxTemp.Checked;
cmd.Parameters["@KwaliteitSensor"].Value = CheckKwaliteit.Checked;
cmd.Parameters["@Toerental"].Value = CheckBoxToerenTal.Checked;
cmd.Parameters["@OlieVerbruik"].Value = CheckBoxOlieVerbruik.Checked;
```

What am I doing wrong or can I solve my checkbox problem in an easier way?

Hope you guys have the answer!

Comment: Can you define *won't work*?  Does it throw an error?  Do you not get the expected results?  Have you checked the values of the `CheckBox*.Checked` objects?

Comment: With wwont work i mean that the screen flashes but doesnt show anything. I doesnt show an error unfortunately. Iwant the datagrid to show the column of the checkbox that is checked. And i also checked the values of the checkbox objexts but that doesnt help me either.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
cmd.Parameters["@DrukSensor"].Value = CheckBoxDruk.Checked;
```

to:

```
cmd.Parameters["@DrukSensor"].Value = CheckBoxDruk.Checked?1:0;
```

for all the checkbox.checked items.

Or (better) take out all the params.Add and change them to AddWithValue()

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrukSensor",CheckBoxDruk.Checked?1:0);
```

Comment: Better approach would be `cmd.Parameters.Add("@DrukSensor", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = CheckBoxDruk.Checked;`

Comment: Both options did unfortunately didnt work :( The screen still flashes but doesnt show anything in the grid view.

Comment: Ok - I misunderstood. Your code is for a database query. If you need help correlating checkboxes to columns, please amend your question to show the columns of your grid and your checkboxes and the logic you use to change column visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Rico,

What datatype does the database have for the following fields?
DrukSensor,FlowSensor,TempSensor,KwaliteitSensor,Toerental,OlieVerbruik

If they utilize small ints in the db, then the following should work.

```
 cmd.Parameters["@DrukSensor"].Value = CheckBoxDruk.Checked ? 1 :0;
 cmd.Parameters["@FlowSensor"].Value = CheckBoxFlow.Checked ? 1 : 0;
 cmd.Parameters["@TempSensor"].Value = CheckBoxTemp.Checked ? 1 :0;
 cmd.Parameters["@KwaliteitSensor"].Value = CheckKwaliteit.Checked ? 1:0;
 cmd.Parameters["@Toerental"].Value = CheckBoxToerenTal.Checked ? 1 : 0;
 cmd.Parameters["@OlieVerbruik"].Value = CheckBoxOlieVerbruik.Checked ? 1: 0;
```

Checkboxes.Checked is a Boolean value. If your fields are stored in the db as Boolean then you will need to figure out how to specify that value in the parameter.

```
cmd.Paramters[@DrukSensor"].Value = CheckBoxDruk.Checked ? "true" : "false";
```

or some such.

Hope this helps.

Comment: They are all floats in my database. Does that change a lot ?

Comment: Seems odd to use floats in a db to represent Boolean values, doesn't it? What are these Sensor fields in the database and what are you trying to do with the checkboxes? Are you trying to use the checkboxes to show/not show columns on the screen? Cause that's way different.

Comment: The data in the database will be information from sensors, thats why i need to use floats. And i need the checkboxes to say to my sql query to get the specific rows i need for my report. i think i do need to show or not show colums on the screen if this doesnt work.

Comment: Rico, you seemingly want to display different columns in your grid based upon checkboxes on a form. Your general strategy will be to manually place a grid on the form. You will have to define its columns manually (depending upon which columns your users wishes to see based upon checkbox values) and then query your table and fill out the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cmd.Parameters["@DrukSensor"].Value = CheckBoxDruk.Checked;
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters["@DrukSensor"].Value = CheckBoxDruk.CheckState;
```

or

```
If(CheckBoxDruk.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
  cmd.Parameters["@DrukSensor"].Value = 1;
else
  cmd.Parameters["@DrukSensor"].Value = 0;
```

View [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkstate(v=vs.110).aspx) for information about CheckBox.CheckState property.